# Texturing a 3D sphere(Can not find a post that helps me)

Tags: 3d, geometry, textures

I am trying to create a 3D sphere and I currently have a sphere made out of points though I need to apply a texture to this and that is causing me problems.

The code for generating the sphere looks like this:

```
    public Sphere(float radius, double step) {


    this.mRaduis = radius;
    this.mStep = step;
    sphereVertex = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(400000)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mPoints = build();
    Log.d("ALIS CHECK!!!!!", " COUNT:" + mPoints);

}

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, sphereVertex);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // workaround bug 3623
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, sphereVertex);

    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, mPoints);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}


private int build() {


    double dTheta = mStep * DEG;
    double dPhi = dTheta;
    int points = 0;

    for (double phi = -(Math.PI); phi <= Math.PI; phi += dPhi) {
        // for each stage calculating the slices
        for (double theta = 0.0; theta <= (Math.PI * 2); theta += dTheta) {
            sphereVertex.put((float) (mRaduis * Math.sin(phi) * Math
                    .cos(theta))); //y-coord
            sphereVertex.put((float) (mRaduis * Math.sin(phi) * Math
                    .sin(theta))); //z
            sphereVertex.put((float) (mRaduis * Math.cos(phi))); //x
            points++;

        }
    }
```

and in my rendering class it looks like this:

```
 public SphereRenderer(Context context) {

    mSphere = new Sphere(1, 25);

    this.context = context;

    vibrator = SphereActivity.getVibrator();
    sphereActivity = SphereActivity.getInstance();



}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Sphere.loadTexture(gl, context, R.drawable.android);

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();


    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);

    rotateSphere(gl, startTime);


    // gl.glRotatef(xRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // gl.glRotatef(yRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    mSphere.draw(gl);

    numFrames++;
    long fpsElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - fpsStartTime;
    if (fpsElapsed > 5 * 1000) { // every 5 seconds
        float fps = (numFrames * 1000.0F) / fpsElapsed;
        Log.d("FPS", "Frames per second: " + fps + " (" + numFrames
                + " frames in " + fpsElapsed + " ms)");
        fpsStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        numFrames = 0;
    }
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fpsStartTime = startTime;
    numFrames = 0;
    if (height == 0) {
        height = 1;
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f,
            100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}
```

I would really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Is it that you don't know how to do texture mapping in OpenGL at all? Or do you need help calculating the texture coordinates for the vertices?

Comment: I don't know much about texture mapping at all, first time I try it. Been reading a bit about it, but have not been able to figure out how to make it fit my code

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to try texture mapping a simple quad first.

Comment: Don't have time for that I think.. it's for a school project and soon time for hand-in so that's why I've turned here :)

Comment: I heavily suggest you to delve a little deeper into the basics of OpenGL and computer graphics in general if you want to really understand what you are doing. And if you don't want, then this place is not www.write-my-homework.com.

Comment: I'm not asking someone to do it for me but a little help would be nice! I can't find a place where I can learn how to do this and I've been trying on my own for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* theoretically texture points, one pixel of texture means you would need a lot of points to do create a recognisable map. From what I can tell you need to draw your sphere as a set of triangles instead, which you can then apply textures to. Effectively this means just combining the points you have to create faces. Rather than `GL_POINTS` you probably want to look at using `GL_TRIANGLES` - see the [OpenGL programming guide on points lines and polygons](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html#name2) for a proper explanation.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a GL_TRIANGLE_ARRAY only GL_TRIANGLE etc. doesn't look quite right though

Comment: You can perfectly texture points (as long as every point has a meaningful texture coordinate), why shouldn't this be possible. Every point produces at least one fragment and has a texture coordinate, what's needed more? But of course this may not be what the OP wants, but just because a texture on a single pixel doesn't make that much sense in the classical sense of a texture doesn't mean it's not possible. As the OpenGL pipeline defines what is possible.

Comment: Just replacing `GL_POINTS` with `GL_TRIANGLES` won't magically produce the correct surface. You most probably will need to reorder the vertices you send to the GL to form triangles. And `GL_TRIANGLE_ARRAY` is rubbish anyway.

Comment: How do I reorder them?/know which order is the correct for them to be

Comment: If a textured point is a single pixel of texture, you might as well just colour them though, so even if you can texture them, unless you have some very detailed point cloud, it's not going to be very recognisable, as well as being very different from my interpretation of the question. I will edit accordingly.